# Capitalise every first letter of a string in an array of strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, typescript, capitalization

I am basically taking a URL like http://localhost:3000/north-america/america and then after the third slash putting each entry into an array.

I have an array of strings like this ["america", "north-america"].

I want to capitalise every first letter of each entry and each word in each entry and then join the strings back together to give me this result ["America", "North-America].

I also want to remove the dashes from any entry and replace them with a space giving me the final result of ["America", "North America].

So far I have managed to get this ["America", "North america"] but I am struggling to capitalise the second word.

```
const urls = "http://localhost:3000/north-america/america"

useEffect(() => {
    if (withAvailabilityChecker === true && urlS !== undefined) {
      const url = urlS;
      let parts: string[] = [];

      parts = url.split('/');
      parts.splice(0, 3);
      parts.reverse();
      parts.splice(0, 1);

      const newParts: string[] = [];

      parts.forEach(el => {
        const removeDashes = el.replaceAll('-', ' ');
        const capitaliseEntry = removeDashes.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + removeDashes.slice(1);
        newParts.push(capitaliseEntry);
      });

      if (newParts.length > 2) {
        newParts.length = 2;
      }
      const result = newParts.join(',' + ' ');

      setInputVal(result);
    }
  }, [urlS, locationName]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd split the string by space, capitalize every word and join them back:

```
const capitaliseEntry = 
    removeDashes.split(' ').map(w => w[0].toUpperCase() + w.slice(1)).join(' ');
```

Comment: Okay this makes sense but seems to cut off the other entry so I am left with just North America

Comment: @ashleyg this is done per part, not on the entire URL. it should replace the line `        const capitaliseEntry = removeDashes.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + removeDashes.slice(1);` you currently have

Comment: I essential need it to be able to do it via the entire url so by splitting by space it will split the url into two arrays [america] , ["north", "america"] but I then need to do the capitalisation and then join these both back together again in one array giving me the result of ["America", "North America"]. At the moment all I am receiving is [North America] .Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 3):

- First things first, in your code

```js
      parts = url.split('/');
      parts.splice(0, 3);
      parts.reverse();
      parts.splice(0, 1);
```

Why do you have the last line, aka `parts.splice(0, 1)`? Since as far I understood your question, you want all the entries from the 3rd slash, and this last line just removes the last element. So you gave the example of `http://localhost:3000/north-america/america`, by your code, it would simply return `["north-america"]`, not `america` since it is removed by the last line of your code.

- On getting the array, you can map all the items to remove the Dashes first, then you could capitalize it. Like the following example.

```
const data = parts.map((element: string) => {
    const dashesRemoved = element.replace(/-/g, " ");
    const dashesRemovedWords = dashesRemoved.split(" ");
    const dashesRemovedCapitalized= dashesRemovedWords.map((word: string) => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase());

    return dashesRemovedCapitalized.join(" ");
});
```

Now all these variables are for clarity on what's going on, and if you want, you can actually combine **all** those functions, like this

```
const data = parts.map((element: string) => element.replace(/-/g, " ").split(" ").map((word: string) => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase()).join(" "));
```

- Also I see you are declaring parts like this

```
      let parts: string[] = [];

      parts = url.split('/');
```

But you don't even have any intermediate code, or so it seems. Then wouldn't it be better to initialize your variable by

```
const parts: string[] = url.split("/");
```

Comment: i forgot to add the last / haha thanks for both answers guys

Answer (score 2):

Using an [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) object to isolate the [`pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) and split to return individual path strings. Then [`String#replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regex and [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters) to simultaneously remove dashes and capitalize first letters.

```js
const
  titleCase = (s) => s.replace(/\b([-\w])/g, m => m === '-' ? ' ' : m.toUpperCase()),

  url = "http://localhost:3000/north-america/america",

  data = new URL(url) // URL { href: 'http://localhost:3000/north-america/america', origin: 'http://localhost:3000', protocol: 'http:', username: '', password: '', host: 'localhost:3000', hostname: 'localhost', port: '3000', pathname: '/north-america/america', search: '', searchParams: URLSearchParams { }, hash: ''}
    .pathname         // "/north-america/america"
    .slice(1)         // "north-america/america"
    .split('/')       // ["north-america", "america"]
    .map(titleCase)   // ["North America", "America"]
    .reverse();       // ["America", "North America"]

console.log(data.join(', '));
```

Answer (score 1):

Step by step is the best approach.

- First split the URL using the `/` character as a divisor.

```js
let parts: string[] = url.split("/")
```

- Get rid of everything before the first three slashes.

```js
parts = parts.slice(3)
```

- Look through each item in the parts array for any `-` characters and remove them.
- Split each item into separate words.
- Capitalise the first letter of each word.
- Join words back into an item.

```js
parts = parts.map(item => {

    // Replacing dashes with spaces
    item = item.replace(/-/g, " ")

    
    item = item.split(" ") // Splitting each part into separate words
               .map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)) // Capitalising the first letter of each word
               .join(" ") // Joining back capitalised words

    return item
})
```

- Finally reverse the array to put parts in the right order

```js
parts = parts.reverse()
```

#### Full Verbose Solution

```js
let url = "http://localhost:3000/north-america/america"

let parts = url.split("/")

parts = parts.slice(3)

parts = parts.map(item => {
  item = item.replace(/-/g, " ")
  
  item = item
    .split(" ")
    .map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
    .join(" ")

  return item
})


parts = parts.reverse()


console.log(parts) // Outputs: ["America", "North America"]
```

#### Full Non-Verbose Solution

```js
let url = "http://localhost:3000/north-america/america"

let parts = url
  .split("/")
  .slice(3)
  .map(item => {
    return item
      .replace(/-/g, " ")
      .split(" ")
      .map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
      .join(" ")
  }).reverse()


console.log(parts) // Outputs: ["America", "North America"]
```